# populate_sdk fails on 'binutils-crosssdk_2.32.bb:do_configure'

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm playing with a custom image for a development board. The image compiles and works correctly. But if I try and populate the SDK I get an error and I suspect it has something to do with the following:

```
checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-distil-sdk-linux': system `sdk-linux' not recognized
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the log:

```
Sstate summary: Wanted 475 Found 138 Missed 337 Current 441 (29% match, 63% complete)
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux-2.32.0-r0 do_configure: configure failed
ERROR: binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux-2.32.0-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.26922)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.26922
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| NOTE: Running ../configure  --build=x86_64-linux                --host=x86_64-linux             --target=x86_64-distil-sdk-linux                --prefix=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr             --exec_prefix=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr                --bindir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux                --sbindir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux                 --libexecdir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/libexec/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux                 --datadir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share              --sysconfdir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc                 --sharedstatedir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/com             --localstatedir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/var              --libdir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux                 --includedir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include                 --oldincludedir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include              --infodir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/info                 --mandir=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man                   --disable-silent-rules                  --disable-dependency-tracking                   --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native --program-prefix=x86_64-distil-sdk-linux-                 --disable-werror                 --enable-deterministic-archives                 --enable-plugins                                   --with-sysroot=/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/recipe-sysroot                 --disable-install-libbfd                 --enable-poison-system-directories                 --with-lib-path==/opt/distil/0.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/lib:=/opt/distil/0.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/usr/lib                  --disable-static  --disable-nls
| checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-distil-sdk-linux': system `sdk-linux' not recognized
| configure: error: /bin/sh ../config.sub x86_64-distil-sdk-linux failed
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26922:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-distil-sdk-linux/2.32.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.26922)
ERROR: Task (/home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-crosssdk_2.32.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1848 tasks of which 1842 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/tj/OE/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-crosssdk_2.32.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the dash in the vendor name? A GNU triplet consists of "arch-vendor-os" (sometimes "os" is "kernel-system", such as "linux-gnu"). And your vendor name "distil-sdk" contains a dash, which confuses GNU autoconf.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html for details

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  Your distro configuration is setting the SDK name to distil-sdk (presumably by setting SDK_VENDOR), remove the hyphen before sdk.